# Switching between facebook apps on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

I'm integrating some facebook features within an android app. For testing I've made a facebook app of my own, but its likely that the client will create his own fb app and want me to swap the info of my app with theirs after the testing is done.

Since for android, you need to provide a signature/hash key to your android app in your facebook app dashboard, does this mean that my android app is always tied to the same facebook app, or can the credentials easily be swapped in future?

Comment: That question has *nothing* to do with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the app is still in development and not already released to the Android Play store, you can always just change the value of your `APP_ID` in the app to replace yours with the client's fb app id.  The signature/hash key should be the same as long as you're building the app on the same machine.

So when your app is ready for the client,

1. have them tell you the app id so that you can replace it in the code
2. give them the android key hash that you are signing the app with (make sure that you use      the correct key and not the android debug key if this version of your app is going live into the app store) so that they can put it in their app dashboard on Facebook.

I think that is about all the steps necessary to solve your issue.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: How do you get the correct key and not the debug one, by the key tool?

Comment: It should be as simple as running the command `keytool -exportcert -alias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore ~/path/to/release.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` with the keystore that you have created for signing the app

Answer (score 1):

You can put your signature/hash key in any number of facebook apps so there should be no problem.
Furthermore, the facebook app can have as many android signature/hash keys and can be replaced anytime. Try it in the dashboard to confirm.